# Optimal Seat Allocation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an optimal seat allocation algorithm, such that for example, if i have a cinema with capacity 100, and n groups of people, i want to choose the right groups that will fill in as maximum seats as possible.

The only thing that will work is brute force, but I'm sure there must be cleverer ways to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried starting with the smallest free row, then filling with the largest size that will fit? It's not perfect but I think it'll give you pretty good results. It reminds me of a string pooling algo I wrote once. I saw nearly no difference using heuristic similar to this vs a much more complicated heuristic that looked one step ahead. As far as an optimal solution you probably need to indeed brute force, in factorial time. You might also try splitting the problem into smaller pieces somehow and brute forcing those individually.

Comment: You could have a look at defragmentation algorithms. The solve the same problem.

Comment: Does every group need to be contiguous within the same row? Or can the group spill over to the next row? (i.e. is the problem truly 2D?). Or is it okay to have a members of the same group in different rows so long as they are sitting directly in front or behind one another?

Comment: Well, the problem is not 2D. The groups are represented only as an array. E.g. mygroups=[10,20,50,60], meaning there are groups of 10,20,50 and 60 people. So in this case the algo should output that the most beneficial decision will be to choose 10,20,60 which will be 90 in total and less than 100. So no need to check for the exact places, like in a matrix.

Comment: So it's a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), then?

Comment: It's a special case of the knapsack problem known as the subset sum problem.

Comment: This problem has large similarity to the knapsack proble. The difference is that in the knapsack problem two values are taken into account- the weight and the value of the item. Here it is only one, which is the number of groups.

Comment: Apriori, thanks a lot. It is actually the subset sum problem.

Comment: IIRC, *SubsetSum* only identifies if there is a perfect/exact fit, it does not identify the "best fit".

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well it's easy to reconstruct it though. If you have a solvability black box, just check whether after removing item i you can reach sum S - i. If yes, you don't need to take item i. If no, you need to take i. Also most algorithms (including the straightforward DP algorithm that I would recommend here) allow for a very easy reconstruction of the optimal solution without having to solve several subproblems

Comment: @RBarryYoung: yes you are correct. I think this may be a good solution to finding a maximal sum: http://crab.rutgers.edu/~guyk/ex/part.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the Knapsack problem known as the Subset Sum problem. There is a lot of work already done on this so the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is a good jumping off point discussing many possible algorithms. The correct choice in algorithm will depend on the sort of data you’re operating on.